# ngclass change color when click

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make favourite, when click it should be changing the color, but it only changing color when I reload page. I need it changing when I click without need to reload page.This my code and  demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-pjpply).

**HTML**

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="conference.favourite === true" [ngClass]="{'true' : conference.favourite === true?'true' :  flag === true? true:false}"  (click)="unfavour(conference.conferenceId)">favorite</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="conference.favourite === false" [ngClass]="{'false' : conference.favourite === false?'false' :  flag === false? false:true}"  (click)="passFavor(conference.conferenceId)">favorite</mat-icon>
```

**Component**

```
public flag: boolean = false;

GetFavourite(event){
    const userid = this.service.getUserId();
    console.log(userid, event)

      let requestData = {
        userId:userid,
        conferenceId:event,
        favourite:true
      }
      return this.http.favourite(requestData).subscribe(res =>{
        this.flag = this._conference['favourite'];
        console.log(this._conference['favourite']);
      })

  }

unfavourite(event){
    const userid = this.service.getUserId();
    let requestData = {
      userId:userid,
      conferenceId:event,
      favourite:false
    }
    return this.http.favourite(requestData).subscribe(res =>{
      this.flag = this._conference['favourite'];
      console.log(this._conference['favourite']);
    })
  }
```

CSS

```
.true{
    color: #FF4040;
}
.false{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: Side Note: *Its reserved words like true/false which should not be used as class names*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  I've provided stackblitz demo

Comment: Is this what you want? --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-q2jke1

Comment: Thank you so much brother it working!!.. Can you add it in answer? I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the code clear with ngClass condition, like:

```
[ngClass]="hero.fav ? 'primary' : 'secondary'"
```

and modify the `hero.fav` the property, which is associated with each option so no need to maintain one local variable to toggle the clicks or classes.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="test(hero.fav = !hero.fav)">
    <div [ngClass]="hero.fav ? 'primary' : 'secondary'" (click)="test(hero.id)">{{ hero.name }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.primary {
  color: red;
}
.secondary {
  color: green;
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-q2jke1)

Answer (score 1):

Some Brackets have been added you condition might not be proper

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="conference.favourite === true" [ngClass]="{'true' : (conference.favourite === true)? true :  (flag === true) ? true:false}"  (click)="unfavour(conference.conferenceId)">favorite</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="conference.favourite === false" [ngClass]="{'false' : (conference.favourite === false) ? false :  (flag === false)? false:true}"  (click)="passFavor(conference.conferenceId)">favorite</mat-icon>
```

Comment: It still I need to reload to change color